# Render reactjs components with razor in index.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is a demo of CRUD(Create,Update,Delete) MVC 5 app + Entity Framework + Reactjs

I'm trying to convert the tags below into reactjs components and render whole page but the problem is the razor lines. When rendering it just shows the text.

What should I do?

Customer View Index:

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="root">

</div>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New Customer", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Reacjs.jsx

```
class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Table">
                @Html.ActionLink("Add New Customer", "Create")
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Table />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: dont't treat react as a template it's rather client-side app running in browser. React/JSX is compiled separately. - it doesn't recognize theese tags (they are server-side). Normally tags are converted into some html(+js?) to communicate with server - React can communicate, too but with more separated/standard ways (API REST or GraphQL). Search for some tutorials about connecting MVC with react.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink` is a C# method which needs to be executed on server. If that is inside a razor view, the view engine will execute it, if it is in another type file (like you have), just user PURE HTML